# Blackberry simulator running on Mac OS

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, macos

Do Blackberry simulators work on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not natively. You'll have to use Boot Camp or a virtual machine running Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an emulator using wine

Here's an example: 
http://azizuysal.com/2009/07/06/blackberry-development-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: I was very interested in this link, however it's a 404 now, can you update it?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't, it was something I found.